# Laravel Baum how to get related models on getAncestorsAndSelf() method

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, package, relation

Using Laravels Baum package for nested sets I try to fetch the relational model on `getAncestorsAndSelf()` but does not work

```
$tree = \App\GroupDeprecator::where('id', $this->team_id)->with('lead')->first();
      dd($tree); //this one shows the user object
      dd($tree->getAncestorsAndSelf());//this one does not shows the user object
```

What went wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

How you solved it? the code looks fine and should work, unless it has been manually updated in the database, I would do:

```
GroupDeprecator::rebuild(true)
```

to update the `lft, rgt and depth` columns